# Is there any way to print to an old Diablo-command-set parallel printer from a modern Mac?

Tags: macos, printing

This question is mostly about software. There exist many hardware adapters that allow one to connect a parallel printer to the USB port on a Mac, but I can't find any way to stream text to the adapter such that it actually prints. Has anybody been able to do this?

Comment: For every printer to work you will need a printer driver. Do you have one ?

Comment: That's just restating my question. Does there exist a printer driver for Diablo-command-set printers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work from the terminal using a standard USB/parallel adapter. Instructions here: http://www.wheels.org/monkeywrench/?p=909